# Limit of the following functions is Riemann Integrable or not?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, riemann-integration

For $0\leq x \leq 1$, let $$f_n(x) = \frac{n}{1+n}, \ \text{if x is irrational} \\ \hspace{15mm}0, \qquad \text{if x is rational}$$

Let $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$. Then to find out whether $f$ s riemmann integrable or not?

According to me $$f(x) = 1, \ \text{if x is irrational} \\ \hspace{15mm}0, \qquad \text{if x is rational}$$

Clearly $f$ is not riemann integrable. But it is given in my notes $f$ is riemann integrable. Where  i am mistaken?

Comment: Why would any of these functions be riemann integrable?

Comment: Upper sum and lower sum are different.

Comment: That's sort of my point, you're taking a limit of not Riemann integrable functions and getting something not Riemann integrable. This doesn't seem particularly surprising, so what's your question exactly? I get that you have something in your notes that's different, but we can't help you unless you can give us an idea of why it's different in your notes.

Comment: Please check the book and remember there could be a typo. Neither $f$ nor any $f_n$ is Riemann-integrable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any partition of $[0,1]$, say $0=x_0<x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_n=1$, then the difference between the upper and lower sum is $$U(f,(x_i))-L(f,(x_i))=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(x_{i+1}-x_i)\left(\sup_{x\in[x_i,x_{i+1}]}f(x)-\inf_{x\in[x_i,x_{i+1}]}f(x)\right)$$
Now for any partition $\sup_{x\in[x_i,x_{i+1}]}f(x)=1$ and $\inf_{x\in[x_i,x_{i+1}]}f(x)=0$. Hence for any partition $$U(f,(x_i))-L(f,(x_i))=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(x_{i+1}-x_i)=1$$
So $f$ is not Reimann integrable.

Answer (score 1):

No. $f$ is not integrable either. Let for any $a,b \in \Bbb R$ $$L_k(f)=\sum_{i=1}^{k} \inf f(t_i)\cdot \Delta x_i\\U_k(f)=\sum_{i=1}^{k} \sup f(t_i)\cdot \Delta x_i$$where $\{t_i\}$ is some partitioning of $[a,b]$ with $t_1=a$  , $t_k=b$. Since any interval $[a,b]$ with $a\ne b$ contains at least one quotient  and one non-quotient real number then $$\inf f(t_i)=0\\\sup f(t_i)=1$$therefore $$L_k(f)=0\\U_k(f)=1$$therefore $R_k(f)$ doesn't exist for any $a,b$ and $f$ is not integrable.